# Best Way to Design These Tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, foreign-keys

Part of my schema for a travel project has the following tables

```
Cruises
Flights
Hotels
CarParking
```

I need a container that wraps one or more of these products into a package. One Cruise/Hotel etc might be part of many packages. I initially thought of

```
Package
- PackageId
- Etc

PackageItem
- PackageItemId
- PackageId (fk)
- ItemId (fk)
- ItemType
```

Where ItemType would indicate whether it's a Cruise, Flight, Hotel etc. I suppose I could use Triggers to enforce referential integrity.

My other idea was

```
Package
- ...

PackageItem
- PackageItemId
- PackageId (fk)
- CruiseId (nullable fk)
- FlightId (nullable fk)
- HotelId (nullable fk)
- CarParkingId (nullable fk)
- etc
```

I suppose each has it pros and cons, but I can't decide. Which do you think is better, which would you choose if you had to implement something like this?

Database is MySql. Platform is C# MVC ASP.NET

(I did search and there were a few similar questions but nothing that corresponded all that well)

Answer (score 5):

The first option is the most flexible.  And I tend to go with flexibility.

**Advantage: Common Queries**

If you want a report on cruises, the query is the same as one for hotels, but with a different WHERE clause.

Using the second form you need to join on and select from different tables.

**Advantage: Growth without Schema Changes*

If you need to add Excursions to your model (something that can *certainly* have many associated to a single package), you just create a new Excursions type.

Using the second form you need to add new fields to your tables, creates new tables to hold the data, and update your queries and logic to use those new tables and fields.

**Cost: Data moving to a form not friendly for human digestion**

Many people could legitimately say that this shouldn't matter at all.  I say that it matters in so far as you have to take account of it...
- It can make debugging harder, so you need to be more regimented and methodical
- It means your GUI has to be smarter in transforming your data for display

Also, although this is a cost, it has the benefit of forcing you into a mid-set where you are less likely so make simplistic assumptions and make sloppy mistakes.  This is a cost that I like to have.

**Falacy: Constraints can't be enforced**

Constraint - Each package component must be either Hotel, Packing, Flight or Cruise
Method - Have a component_type table, and FK to that table

Constraint - Only one of each type allowed per package
Method - UNIQUE constraint on (package_id, component_type_id)

Constraint - Each component can only be within one package
Method - UNIQUE constraint on (component_id)

**Cost - Deferred complexity**

In my opinion, the normalised table to map Packages to Components is actually simple and elegant.  The next step, is to decide how to store the associated details of a component.

A single global "component" table could hold all the fields, but allow them to be nullable.  Thus a HOTEL would have a NULL Flight_Number.  But all components would have a Price.

Or you could create an Entity_Attribute_Value table.  This can be formed in such a way as to prevent hotels having a flight number...
- component_attributes table = (id, type_id, attribute_id, attribute_value)
- (type_id, attribute_id) can be foreign keyed to allowable combinations

It's impossible (afaik) to enforce REQUIRED fields, such as Price.
The Value is often stored as a VARCHAR.
For that reason, and others, search the data by Value becomes hard.

**final opinion**

I would *not* use option 2, as this is highly constrained and merges two considerations together - How to hold data for different component types (hotels, flights, etc) and how to relate them to their parent packages.

I would instead recommend that you consider the multitude of ways for holding the component data, and make that decision based on your needs.  Then relate those components to the packages using a 1:many normalised mapping table.  Your option 1.

Comment: Thanks for the comments and suggestions

Answer (score 3):

You haven't mentioned in question whether you need to support multiple products of same type inside a single package - i.e. whether package can contain multiple Hotels, for example.

1) If support for multiple same-type products per package is required then you should go first way, but maybe split relationships into separate tables per product type, i.e.

```
PackageHotelItem
- PackageItemId
- PackageId (fk)
- HotelId (fk)

PackageCruiseItem
- PackageItemId
- PackageId (fk)
- CruiseId (fk)

... etc.
```

This way you will be able to have referential integrity via normal FK mechanism.

2) If you don't need such support then you may use your second solution.

Comment: This would be my choice, as when new package items come along you don't end up with the `PackageItem` table having loads of fields.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. There does need to be multiple products of the same type in a package. Both my options allow for that as, in both cases, I would have several PackageItems making up a package.

Comment: Your first option is interesting, but arguably more complex to query than my second option. To get a whole package you'd have to query every Package__Item join table, so adding a new product type would be quite painful.

Comment: Yes, queries might be more complex. But you will get clear DB structure that would also be easily extendable if you decide to add, say, RailwayStations at some point. Everything comes with its own pros and cons, including my solution.